# ¿Como puedo arreglar un bucle infinito de una lista por comprensión, para la funcion unit propagate del algoritmo DPLL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, while

Quiero crear el algoritmo DPLL, entonces escribí una función unit propagate, pero cuando la función debe trabajar con dos o más clausulas, la función entra a un bucle infinito, dejare mi código, para una mejor comprensión

```
def check(S):
    if [] in S:
        return False
    for i in S:
        if len(i) == 1:
            return i
    return False

def complemento(literal):
    if '-' in literal:
        return literal[-1]
    else:
        return '-' + literal



def unit_propagate(S,Dic):
    inicial = check(S)
    while inicial != False:
        literal = inicial[0]
        comple = complemento(literal)
        print(inicial)
         
        S1 = [i for i in S if literal not in i]
            
        for i in S1:
            if comple in i:
                i.remove(comple)
          
        if '-' not in literal:
            Dic[literal] = 1
        else:
            Dic[comple] = 0
        inicial = check(S1) 
    return S1, Dic



S = [['p'], ['-p','q','-r'], ['q']]
Dic = {}
a,b = unit_propagate(S,Dic)
print(a,b)
```

Quiero arreglar la variable S1, la cual es la que entra al bucle infinito. Cuando la función recibe la segunda clausula con la que debe trabajar (la letra "q"), este entra al bucle infinito, y se que es porque cuando la variable S1 `S1 = [i for i in S if literal not in i]`, funciona con la lista original (S), pero no con la lista modificada.

Comment: this site is in spanish. translate your question, please

Comment: Ya traduje la pregunta, pido disculpas por el idioma

Comment: solo sobreescribe el valor de S `S = [i for i in S if literal not in i]`